# host_permissions for 1 user specified domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have an extension that currently has host_permission access to 3 different domains. We want to add a 4th. The issue is that this 4th domain will be set by the user in the extension's options page, and could be anything.

I have read about using all_urls as the host_permission and believe it can be done that way. My questions are:

1. Is there no other way to give permission to the specific domain the user sets up in options? (Something like the background script would see a new domain there and prompt the user for permission to access that 1 domain)
2. Is there potentially any issues with getting pass Google's approval process when using all_urls? We would be using all_urls to access just 1 domain, which I read was an issue at least in the past, but in our case that 1 domain is unknown at install time.

Comment: See `optional_host_permissions` and chrome.permissions.request

Comment: My understanding is optional_host_permissions and chrome.permissions.request manage which actions (storage, alarms, ect) are allowed to happen, not which domains they are allowed happen on.

Comment: You confused it with `optional_permissions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sample adds host to origins on request button click.
Also, click the getAll button to display origins and permissions on the console.

Adding to origins without user gesture will result in the following error:

> "Unchecked runtime.lastError: This function must be called during a user gesture"

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "optional_host_permissions",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.google.com/"
    ],
    "optional_host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

myscript.js

```js
const elmRequest = document.getElementById("request");
const elmGetAll = document.getElementById("getAll");

elmRequest.onclick = () => {
    request();
}

elmGetAll.onclick = () => {
    getAll();
}

function request() {
    chrome.permissions.request({
        origins: ["https://hoge.com/"]
    }, (granted) => {
        console.log(granted);
    });
}

function getAll() {
    chrome.permissions.getAll((permissions) => {
        console.log(permissions);
    });
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body style="min-width:250px">
    <input type="button" id="request" value="request"><br>
    <input type="button" id="getAll" value="getAll">
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer has everything needed. I have not tested via the store yet, but seems to work when loading an unpacked extension locally.